# Running impala service alone in docker

Tags: impala, mapr

I am trying to install impala in a docker container(using MAPR documentstion).In this docker I am running only Impala service and remaining hive,maprfs services will be running on physical node.When starting impala-server(impala daemon) I am getting wearied errors.I just wanted to know whether this kind of installation is possible or not.

Thanks for Help!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it depends on your Impala and MapR version. Impala 2.2.0 is supported on MapR 5.x. Impala 2.5.0 is supported on MapR 5.1 and later. Check [enter link description here](https://maprdocs.mapr.com/home/InteropMatrix/r_impala_matrix.html) before proceeding.